# Capture Screen (Specific Window) with Python

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, screen-recording

I want the ability to capture my screen (ideally from a specific application) using Python. Is it possible to do this?

If not, is it possible to build a GUI in Python that is transparent so I can drag it over a pre-existing application and visually capture what's behind it?

Can cv2 preform this? Not sure what to put inside "VideoCapture" though.

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(....)
```

I have found solutions online that capture the entire screen. Is it possible to select a specific window/application for capturing?

Comment: do you use Windows, Linux or MacOS ?

Comment: PyAutoGui has function [screenshot](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#screenshot-functions) but it captures full screen. On Linux it uses program `scrot` which can capture active/focused window so you can use `scrot` with module subprocess to capture active/focused window.

Comment: Plan to use this on a Mac.